# check Equal and Not Equal conditons for double values

Tags: java, android, double

I am facing difficulty in comparing two `double values` using `==` and `!=`.

I have created 6 double variables and trying to compare in `If` condition.

```
double a,b,c,d,e,f;

if((a==b||c==d||e==f))
{
//My code here in case of true condition
}
else if ((a!=b||c!=d||e!=f))
{
//My code here in case false condition
}
```

Though my condition is `a and b are equal` control is going to `else if` part

So I have tried `a.equals(b)` for equal condition, Which is working fine for me.

My query here is how can I check `a not equal b`. I have searched the web but I found only to use `!=` but somehow this is not working for me.

Comment: If `a.equals(b)` worked, try `!a.equals(b)`.

Comment: ok thanks... I didn't get this thought will try now..

Comment: == should work if a and b same,if it's not work and .equals work probably you have created Double variables instead double

Comment: @Christian Thanks for your help I am able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a `double` (the primitive type) then `a` and `b` must not be equal.

```
double a = 1.0;
double b = 1.0;
System.out.println(a == b);
```

If `.equals()` works you're probably using the object wrapper type `Double`. Also, the equivalent of `!=` with `.equals()` is

```
!a.equals(b)
```

**Edit**

Also,

```
else if ((a!=b||c!=d||e!=f))
{
  //My code here in case false condition
}
```

(Unless I'm missing something) should just be

```
else 
{
  //My code here in case false condition
}
```

if you really want invert your test conditions **and** test again,

```
 else if (!(a==b||c==d||e==f))
```

Or use [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
 else if (a != b && c != d && e != f)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
 !a.equals(b) || !c.equals(d) || !e.equals(f)
```

Well with double data type you can use

```
 ==,!= (you should try to use these first.. )
```