# Use values from a textfield to use if / else

Tags: java, netbeans

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  Double NumEmpilhador;      
  Double TamanhoFonte;
  Double TempoEmpilhador;
  Double ResultadoEmpilhador;

         NumEmpilhador = Double.parseDouble(NumeroEmp1.getText());
         TamanhoFonte = Double.parseDouble(ValorEmpilhador.getText());
         TempoEmpilhador = Double.parseDouble(OperaçãoEmp1.getText());

         if(NumEmpilhador==0){
                EmpilhadorFinal1.setText("0");
         }
         else{
            ResultadoEmpilhador=(NumEmpilhador*TamanhoFonte*TempoEmpilhador)/24; 
            EmpilhadorFinal1.setText(ResultadoEmpilhador + "W");
         }
}
```

I want when the value of textfield is "0" that places the number "0" in jlabel, if the value is other than "0" that does the math operation.
However, in the part of the mathematical operation (when the value is different from "0") runs well, but when it is equal to "0" the program gives us an error.
How can I resolve this? If it can be with a practical example in thanks, I'm still in the initial phase with java.

Here is the error I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecima‌​l.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:11‌​0)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at tese4.Camara1a3.jButton2ActionPerformed(Camara1a3.java:6499)
```

I tried this: `if (NumeroEmp1.getText().equals(0))` and this: `if (NumeroEmp1.getText().equals("0"))`. And it still does not work.

Thank you!

Comment: what is the error exception do you get? Since you are getting a Double `.equals()` will work. suppose you refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902801/check-equal-and-not-equal-conditons-for-double-values)

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String


 
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
 
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
 
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
 
at tese4.Camara1a3.jButton2ActionPerformed(Camara1a3.java:6499)

Comment: i try this: 
if(NumeroEmp1.getText().equals(0))
and
if(NumeroEmp1.getText().equals("0"))
And it still does not work.

Comment: The text field that you reference on line 6499 is blank.  You'll need work out how you want to handle this case.

Comment: Beware of case. My guess is you want primitive `double`, not `Double` objects. And according to conventions, variable names should begin with a lowercase letter, e.g., `numEmpilhador` and `tamanhoFonte` (when asking people kindly to read through your code, it’s considerate to follow the conventions).

Comment: Thank you for providing the new and useful information (some of it in response to @RajithPemabandu’s question). When doing that, it’s a good idea to edit your origianl question and add the information there. And please format a stack trace as code, or it’s pretty hard to read. This time I did it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you've debugged your code, you'd see that the error comes up at line

`TamanhoFonte = Double.parseDouble(ValorEmpilhador.getText());`

This line and the following one try to fetch a text and cast it to a double value but these fields are empty. So, you get a [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)

I'd suggest you remove those lines if you're not interested in what is typed in that TextFields.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
    if (NumeroEmp1.getText().isEmpty()) {
        // user did not enter a number
    } else {
        // we’ve got a number, proces it
    }
```

The message `empty String` tells you that the string you were trying to parse was empty (in other words, it was `""`).

You may also want to catch the case where the user enters something, but this something is not a valid double number. You can use a `try`-`catch` block for that.